# C++ Granting Access

Tags: class, c++11, inheritance, public, protected

in C++,
While granting access demoting a variable from protected to public is not allowed but it is happening.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
    protected: int x;    // x is protected
};

class derived: private base { 
    public: base::x;     //demoting from protected to public must not happen
};

int main(){
    derived d1;
    d1.x=10;            //protected variable x is being accessed using an object**
    cout<<d1.x<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why this code works? Or why it does not work? Or what can be changed to prevent it from working?

Comment: Suppose base variable name was ``y`` and derived class used ``int x = base::y``. Then I hope you don't see any problem with your example

Comment: The reason the code works is that in derived class in public section compiler is treating your code like  ``int x  = base::x `` and derived class x variable is public

Comment: @KarstenKoop  sorry for not clarifying before ,I am trying to ask Why does the code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int` object is not what is `protected`, merely the *name* `base::x`

You are incorrect in your claim "protected variable x is being accessed". It is not. `derived::x` is a public member, which merely *refers* to the `base::x`.

The `public` and `protected` members of `base` are visible to `derived`, which is where the `protected` variable `base::x` is being accessed, by the access declaration.

Comment: @nathanesau if we can actually do that then won't it defy the rule that protected members can only be inherited as private or protected

Comment: @SUMIT what rule? There may be an organisational *style rule* that forbids this, but it is not a rule of C++. There are *many many* worse things that are legal C++